# Aggregate Values of Multiple Lookups in Excel

Tags: arrays, excel, function, lookup

I'm looking for a non-VBA solution to this problem.

Say I have a graph (in the computer science sense) in a spreadsheet as follows:

```
    A          B          C           D           
1  Vertex    Neighbors   Degree    Avg Nghbr Deg
2  A         B,C              2              2.5  
3  B         A,C              2              2.5         
4  C         A,B,D            3      1.666666667
5  D         C                1                3
```

I've entered columns C and D by hand but I want them to be calculated automatically. I've found reasonable solutions for column C that essentially count the commas and add 1. But for column D, I can't find a solution. I've found countless articles that explain how to lookup **one** value multiple times in **one** column, and countless articles that explain how to look up **multiple** values once in **multiple** columns, but I can't figure out how to look up multiple values in ONE column, get back an array of values, and then take the average of that array. I'm sure this can be done in VBA but I'd prefer a native Excel solution if one exists.

Obviously I'd like to extend this so that I can do other analyses of a vertex's neighbors. Presumably once I know the method to analyze a "looked-up array" I will be able to use it in other functions as well.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get column C:

```
=LEN(B2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B2,",",""))+1
```

To get column D use SUMPRODUCT with SEARCH:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((ISNUMBER(SEARCH("," & $A$2:$A$5 & ",","," & B2 & ",")))*$C$2:$C$5)/C2
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, didn't even need array functions. If I ever get my PhD I should look you up and buy you a drink...